# If a director of a private limited company in India dies, will their spouse get the profits of the company later?

Tags: corporate-law, india

If I am a director in a private limited company in India with a friend, and I die after some years, will my wife get the profits of the company?

Comment: Obviously depends enormously on what your legal arrangements are. Do you have a will? Do you have a prenuptial agreement, if you got your stake in the company before you married?

Comment: It would also be common for their to be provisions in the company governing documents such as a buy-sell agreement, setting forth the right of their heirs of a deceased owner at death.

Comment: It sounds like you aren your friend also own the company as sole owners, although this isn't entirely clear.

Answer (score 6):

### Directors don’t own companies - they manage them

Shareholders own companies.

So, if you are a director and die, the legal upshot is you are no longer a director and the company may need to replace you in accordance with its rules.

If you are a shareholder, then, subject to any other contracts like a option for the company or other shareholders to buy the shares of a deceased shareholder, the shares will be distributed in accordance with your will or the laws of intestate succession if you don’t have a will. Whoever owns the shares with have the same rights as you did.

Comment: -1, it's blatently obvious that OP is referring to owning the company with their friend.

Comment: @Studoku yes, I answered the unasked but obvious question as well

Comment: Studoku, I wouldn’t make any assumptions. Especially if the answer would be completely wrong with the wrong function. If friends A and B own a company and hire C as director, C’s widow has no rights at all to the company.

Comment: Note that it wouldn't be unusual for a mere director who doesn't own the company to have survivors benefits pursuant an employment agreement, although it doesn't seem that this is what the OP is talking about given the reference to profits.